# regex (php pcre) not validating Currency Sign

Tags: php, regex, validation, pcre

I am using the following regex to check an input field. I want to allow all currency symbols:

```
/^[\w\s\-\#?\!:='\(\)\p{Sc}]+$/
```

It is working - except for the `€` sign.

`\p{Sc}` would mean "match all currencies". The `$` sign is e.g. working - but the `€` sign gets kicked out.

Where is my mistake?
Regards.

Comment: you mean at the end: "\p{Sc}\u" ? Or where to put "\u" ?I also tried that, it says " Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: PCRE does not support \L, \l, \N{name}
, \U, or \u"

Answer (score 1):

Use `u` flag to enable UTF mode, so that the pattern and the input string are treated as Unicode string (in UTF-8 encoding). Without `u` flag, matching operates on bytes and is not Unicode-aware.

```
/^[\p{Sc}\w\s#?!:='()-]+$/u
```

I have also removed unnecessary escape `\` and placed `-` at the end of the character class to avoid escaping.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I had the \u between the [...] brackets.. that's why it did not work.